# Shouting/sending a Blob object does not work in webRTC

Tags: reactjs, websocket, webrtc, blob

I am using this [React library](https://github.com/lazorfuzz/liowebrtc) to shout a JS Blob object but it does not seen to send the Blob.

If I do this to shout the Blob object I get an empty object in payload:

```
console.log('sending', blob); // sending Blob {size: 384, type: "audio/mp3"}
this.props.webrtc.shout('chat', blob);
```

The peer who receives the shout gets `{}`

But if I was to shout something like this:

```
this.props.webrtc.shout('chat', 123);
```

Then the receiver sees `123`.

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome/webrtc.org [does not support sending blobs](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=2276). You need to split it into chunks and send them as arraybuffers. [This sample](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/datachannel/filetransfer/) shows the details

Comment: I tried sending an arrayBuffer but its also an empty object.
`this.props.webrtc.shout('chat', arrayBuff)`; //sending ArrayBuffer(6144) {}`

Comment: however if i send a binary string of that blob then it sends.